# Windows file browser in wine. I want to open selected file in linux program

Tags: wine, filemanager

I wanted a good column view (miller columns) file browser in Ubuntu, but none is available in 18.04. I tried installing pantheon and succeeded installing it after a lot of trouble, but it installed a lot of extra stuff that made my system unstable.
My solution now has been to install UltraExplorer in Wine, which is fantastic, or would be if I could open the files within it in my regular Linux programs.

Is there some way I can make the 'open with' option list Linux software to open my files???

Alternatively, someone can implement this basic functionality within nautilus, but it doesn't look like that will happen any time soon...

Comment: Try one of the options in https://stackoverflow.com/q/6004070/2072269

Comment: There seems to be a solution here. https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_associate_a_native_program_with_a_file_type_in_Wine.3F
It's not easy though...

Comment: And I found this https://ranger.github.io/
I don't usually use terminal based solutions (I'm scared of it, don't bite me), but this seems to work ok so far (super quick test only)

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way is to use [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/download.htm) under Wine.
It's two birds with one stone, because it's my favorite file manager (that Krusader can't even beat by a long shot), and it can easily change the file association. This builds upon the "winebrowser" method on WineHQ (linked in Caleb's comment above)

- Select a file
- Files→Associate With... (Alt+F+A)
- Edit type...
- Replace the program with `winebrowser "%1"`
- Disable DDE
- Save and repeat for every file type